# Haskell: Execute IO action only if a certain time has passed since it's last execution

Tags: haskell, period

I have a media stream with associated named pipe to it. The program reads data from pipe and processes frames with `processFrame`.

```
module Main where
import Codec.FFmpeg
import Codec.FFmpeg.Decode
import Control.Monad.Except (runExceptT)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    initFFmpeg
    -- get IO reader
    eResult <- runExceptT $ frameReader avPixFmtRgb24 (File "pipe")
    case eResult of
        Left err -> do print "couldn't establish frameReader\n"
                       print err
        Right (getMaybeFrame, cleanup) -> do
            -- read and process frames until av_read_frame returns no frames
            loopWhileTrue (getAndProcessFrame getMaybeFrame)
            cleanup
          where
            loopWhileTrue f = do result <- f
                                 case result of
                                    True -> loopWhileTrue f
                                    False -> return ()
      where
        getAndProcessFrame gMF = do
            maybeFrame <- gMF
            case maybeFrame of
                Just frame -> do tc <- timeCondition
                                 if tc
                                 then do processFrame frame
                                 else return ()
                                 return True
                Nothing -> return False
        timeCondition = return True

processFrame :: AVFrame -> IO ()
processFrame frame = do isKeyFrame <- getKeyFrame frame
                        if isKeyFrame
                        then do pts <- getPts frame
                                print pts
                        else return ()
```

I need to perform `processFrame` only once in a minute, bypassing all other frames.

This code does not have a proper time condition, only a `timeCondition` stub.
I planned to write a proper `timeCondition` function which returns `True` when a certain time has passed since last `processFrame`, otherwise `False`. But this looks too imperative and it's not clear how to use Monads/MVars for this. What's the right way of designing such a program in Haskell?

Comment: Either main loopWhileTrue a little more complex, keeping track of the last time a frame was processed, or pass an MVar to getAndProcessFrame then to `processFrame` that contains the last time.  Check the current time against this last time at each frame and conditionally continue or exit early.

Comment: The most obvious code structure improvement would be to make `loopWhileTrue` a top-level binding instead of burying it in a `case` expression inside a `do` block. Also, you can write it `loopWhileTrue f = do { result <- f; when result $ loopWhileTrue f }`, or even `loopWhileTrue f = fix $ \m -> do { result <- f; when result m }`. These will give type signatures `loopWhileTrue :: Monad m => m Bool -> m ()`.

Comment: Is there no way of sleeping the thread for a minute? (in `loopWhileTrue`)

Comment: @Alec It looks like OP wants to continue receiving frames while waiting (but discarding them unprocessed).

Comment: @AleXoundOS Cleaning up your code is an excellent question for Code Review.

Comment: @RowanBlush agreed! it's not very clear from the narrative whether the code currently works as intended though. or does it?

Answer (score 3):

Grab a timestamp when the processing step completes with [`getCurrentTime`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.6.0.1/docs/Data-Time-Clock.html#v:getCurrentTime) and thread it back through your loop, then `timeCondition` is just some math on time values.

```
import Data.Time.Clock

-- | Returns `True` when 60 seconds have passed from the given value.
-- Not respectful of leap seconds.
isAMinuteSince :: UTCTime -> IO Bool
isAMinuteSince timestamp = do
    now <- getCurrentTime
    return $ diffUTCTime now timestamp >= 60
```